# OpenCL code to work with both AMD/Nvidia

Tags: sdk, opencl, nvidia, amd-processor

Could someone tell if it's possible to get an OpenCL code working with both AMD and Nvidia cards after compilation and what is the general procedure for that?
Do I need to get both OpenCL SDKs (AMD/Nvidia) installed and with an "if" structure make different code for each cases (AMD device or Nvidia device)?
If you could just clarify a bit with some headlines would appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, this is the purpose of OpenCL over CUDA (which only works with NVIDIA hardware). Basically you make your code writing kernels in C99 which one will then be compiled in an intermediate "manufacturer independent" code. That last code will then be interpreted by your card (AMD or Nvidia) during the runtime.
Normally, there is no reason why you should write different card specific code neither use different SDK (but well… I'm on Max OS 10.7 which possibly differs from other environment)

Comment: Thanks Flavien, so if I compile a sample using OpenCL and AMD sdk for example, it should work with Nvidia card? Or will I be missing something?

Comment: The AMD BLAS and FFT libraries also run on NVIDIA devices, as do the ArrayFire OpenCL libraries.  Very convenient!

Comment: If you are looking for performance you may have to do vendor specific tuning, for AMD you can run your openCL kernel through Kernel Analyzer and check out the resulting Intermediate Language as well as ISA code that will run on the hardware.

Comment: @ocluser: Can you clarify what you mean by "Do vendor specific tunning to get performance"? Can I just not write an optimized code to get performance (when using OpenCL and dividing tasks depending on the number of cores, size of the task, etc.) ....that actually work with both Nvidia/AMD?

Comment: @Maiss:Well you can write general optimization, but to increase the performance you need to look at the generated IL/PTX and ISA code and also look at the Vendor specs such as Register size, LDS, Global Memory. 1. When creating workgroups you need to factor in number of wavefronts/warp, LDS,cache etc, you need to size workgroup properly to hide latency. 2. Improperly mapping loop operations to OpenCLthreads can significantly reduce performance 3. Vectorization is important such as use float4 instead of float 4 4. some AMD h/w is built using VLIW5 so 4 scalar operation and 1 transcedental..

Comment: continuing... Operation, Both NVIDIA/AMD gives performance/profiling tools, they tell you different things about the kernel such as occupancy, memory/buffer usage, kerenl runtime, view of IL/PTX, ISA code etc, Within GPU generation there is different tuning mechanism for ex AMD 5XXX series tuning may not work well in AMD 7xxx southern island cards .. so on IMHO you need to do vendor specific tuning if you are planning to get maximum performance out of the hardware.

Comment: @Ocluser: Thank you very much, It's time to dive into the beast now :)